# List<Int16>? as an method parameter

Tags: c#, .net, list, nullable

Error message cannot have non-nullable parameter

How can I pass a List? to a method?

```
public int RegexAutoCode(int sID, List<Int16>? valueIDs, string text, SqlCommand cmd)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as a `List<>?` - `List` is a reference type regardless of the element type, and so is already nullable:

```
// This is absolutely fine
List<Int16> list = null;
```

If you wanted a `List` of nullable `Int16` values (so each *element* can be null or an `Int16`) then you want a parameter like this:

```
List<Int16?> valueIDs
```

For [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) to be valid, `T` has to be a non-nullable value type. That's what the `T : struct` constraint indicates.

Answer (score 1):

Use `List<Int16?>`

You had the `?` in the incorrect place.